# hazelcast how to enable user code deployment at member side

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm really new to hazelcast and I'm referring closely to this question [How to fix Hazelcast from throwing 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: User Code Deployment is not enabled' for EntryProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475002/how-to-fix-hazelcast-from-throwing-java-lang-illegalstateexception-user-code-d), trying to run the sample codebase for the EntryProcessor. And from my understanding I need to "enable user code deployment" at the member side.

However, on referring to the documentation here, I'm not too sure how to enable this (based on the same project structure and codebase found here - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples)

```
<hazelcast>
    ...
    <user-code-deployment enabled="true">
        <class-cache-mode>ETERNAL</class-cache-mode>
        <provider-mode>LOCAL_AND_CACHED_CLASSES</provider-mode>
        <blacklist-prefixes>com.foo,com.bar</blacklist-prefixes>
        <whitelist-prefixes>com.bar.MyClass</whitelist-prefixes>
        <provider-filter>HAS_ATTRIBUTE:lite</provider-filter>
    </user-code-deployment>
    ...
</hazelcast>
```

```
        Config config = new Config();
        UserCodeDeploymentConfig distCLConfig = config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
        distCLConfig.setEnabled( true )
                .setClassCacheMode( UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ClassCacheMode.ETERNAL )
                .setProviderMode( UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ProviderMode.LOCAL_AND_CACHED_CLASSES )
                .setBlacklistedPrefixes( "com.foo,com.bar" )
                .setWhitelistedPrefixes( "com.bar.MyClass" )
                .setProviderFilter( "HAS_ATTRIBUTE:lite" );
```

Couldn't find this part in the codebase, and not sure where to insert the programmatic part either. Could I get some advice on how to implement this part to make the example code work? (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/clusters/deploying-code-on-member.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest configuration to enable Hazelcast User Code Deployment on the member side is the following configuration and you can start from it.

```java
Config config = new Config();
config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig().setEnabled(true);
```